# ImportError: cannot import name 'inf'

Tags: python, math, import, importerror

I'm new in Python and i have this problem. When I run my scripts it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./message", line 2, in <module>
    from src.graph_lib import *
  File "/export/home/xsymersk/TGR/src/graph_lib.py", line 2, in <module>
    from math import inf
ImportError: cannot import name 'inf'
```

My code has this import structure:

graph_lyb.py:

```
from src.dfs_lib import *
from math import inf
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
```

dfs_lib.py:

```
from enum import Enum
```

message.py:

```
from src.graph_lib import *
from sys import stdin
```

forest.py:

```
from src.graph_lib import *
from sys import stdin
```

race.py:

```
from src.graph_lib import *
from sys import stdin
```

Code is running without `inf` import.

Comment: `math.inf` was added in Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to import `inf` from math module. The `math.isinf` function exists but for defining an infinite value you can use `float('inf')`.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, `math.inf` is new with python 3.5. `inf` has always been around as `float('inf')` and `math.inf` is really just a convenience. If you like using `math.inf`, you can restrict your code to supported versions

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3,5):
    raise ImportError('{} requires python version 3.5 or later'.format(__name__))
```

or you can just add it yourself

```
import sys
import math
if sys.version_info < (3,5):
    math.inf = float('inf')
    math.nan = float('nan')
    math.tau = math.pi * 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

Which python version do you use?

The `inf` constants in `math`package is implemented at Python 3.5

(related link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.inf)

You should check the version of Python you use.

Comment: oh, i have lower version, is there something as inf?

Comment: i have it, float("inf")